# Using R, find number of rows across multiple dataframes and create list of values

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes of varying numbers of rows.

What I would like to do is acquire the number of rows from dataframe1 (e.g. 5 rows) and assign it a value (e.g. Gene1) & repeat this for dataframe2 (e.g. 2 rows) and assign it a value (e.g. Gene2) to give this list:

```
Gene1
Gene1
Gene1
Gene1
Gene1
Gene2
Gene2
```

Thank you and I would appreciate any help

Comment: What would the final output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a character array that lists the number of rows in your separate data frames, you could do something like this:

```
numrows <- c(5,2) #This is the number of rows in your first two data frames
df <- data.frame() #initialize an empty dataframe to store your results

for(i in 1:length(numrows)){
  df <- append(df,rep(paste0('Gene',i),numrows[i])) #loop over the numrows array and append the results to your data frame
}

df <- data.frame(sapply(df, unlist)) #'reshape' into the desired result
```

You'll also want to create a new title for your column, since it'll be ugly using my somewhat convoluted solution.